# Does a templated variadic constructor affect the triviality of a type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Should `s` be considered a trivial type according to the C++20 standard?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct s {
    s() = default;
    s(auto...) {}
};
static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<s>); // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc ok
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hn96fo31q)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[class.prop]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#2) defines trivial class types:

> A *trivial class* is a class that is trivially copyable and has one or more eligible default constructors ([class.default.ctor]), all of which are trivial.

[[class.default.ctor]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor) defines "default constructor":

> A *default constructor* for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` for which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a default argument (including the case of a constructor with no parameters). [...]

The variadic constructor for `s` is a default constructor because all 0 of its non-pack parameters each have a default argument. So `s` doesn't satisfy the "all of which are trivial" criterion, and is not a trivial class type.

Comment: Just to make it a bit more clear for the non-lawyers amongst us; the variadic constructor of `s` is not trivial (because it's user-provided as `{}`), and it could be used as a default constructor to default construct an `s` (since its parameter pack can collapse to nothing). So, now it boils down to the ruling of a trivial class, which demands that *all* eligible default constructors are trivial (of which the variadic constructor isn't).

Comment: I think gcc and msvc don't consider the template constructor as eligible? I'm not sure how to read the eligible requirement, if this only applies to constraints (with `requires` keyword) or does that also eliminate things that overload resolution would eliminate.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "eligible" is defined here: https://eel.is/c++draft/special#6
It doesn't mean that it would actually be selected by overload resolution.

Comment: @BrianBi Yeah, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Partial_ordering_of_constraints) has a note from standard without mentioning it's a note, which got me confused. It does mention all the steps of selecting which function to call, and it looks like eligibility is related to the selection process. Looking at standard, I see it's a note, so it looks like this is only about constraints. If the template had any constraint at all, `s` would be trivial again.